# How to use nullable columns with Anorm and Play Framework?

Tags: scala, null, playframework, anorm

I have a case class MyRecord that I want to use for every row in a resultset:

```
case class MyRecord(id: Int, remindeMe: Option[org.joda.time.DateTime])
```

How do I SELECT all rows in a table and return a List of MyRecord using Scala and Anorm with Play Framework?

I have tried with:

```
def getRecords() : List[MyRecord] = {
      val records = SQL("SELECT id, data FROM mytable")().collect {
          case Row(id: Int, Some(data: Long)) => 
                      MyRecord(id, new org.joda.time.DateTime(data))
     }
}
```

If the column `data` is null I want `None` otherwise I want `Some(data)` as remindMe in the case class. Yes, the above Scala code is very wrong, but I don't understand how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you have already defined the Option:

```
def getRecords() : List[MyRecord] = {
      SQL("SELECT id, data FROM mytable")().collect {
          case Row(id: Int, Some(data: Long)) => 
                  MyRecord(id, Some(new org.joda.time.DateTime(data)))
          case Row(id: Int, None) => 
                  MyRecord(id, None)

     }
}
```

The case that you paste would ignore all the None results as they would not match Some(data)

EDIT: adding the "toList" at the end solves it, as @kassens said. I tested it in a Play 1.2.2-Scala 0.91 env. There's a way to give the points to him? :)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get it to a list? Now I get this error: `Error raised is : type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[models.MyRecord] required: List[models.MyRecord]`

Comment: @Jonas collect should return the list, I've updated the code, the val shouldn't be in there. Did a quick test in a Scala env (No play Anorm though) and it worked

Comment: Yes, I also removed the `val records` before I run the code. It is the current code that returns `scala.collection.immutable.Stream[models.MyRecord]` instead of `List[models.MyRecord]`

Comment: @Jonas I'll need to get to a PLay-scala env, I don't have that here. I update later on

Comment: I guess you can just append a `.toList` after the closing `}` from the `collect`.

Comment: @kassens: When I add `.toList` I get this error: `Error raised is : missing parameter type for expanded function ((x0$1) => x0$1 match { case Row((id @ (_: Int)), Some((data @ (_: Long)))) => MyRecord(id, Some(new org.joda.time.DateTime(data))) case Row((id @ (_: Int)), None) => MyRecord(id, None) })`